# how to pass a text field value to other page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am working on wordpress and i get the location data of user like zip code i would like to know that i want to send this zip code to other page on button click. these are my form fields and i only want to show zip code on other page.

```
 <div id="locationField">
<input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address" /></div>
<table id="address">
<tbody>
<tr style="display: none;">
<td class="label" style="display: none;">Street address</td>
<td class="slimField"><input id="street_number" class="field" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td>
<td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input id="route" class="field" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<td class="label" style="display: none;">City</td>
<td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input id="locality" class="field" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label" style="display: none;">State</td>
<td class="slimField"><input id="administrative_area_level_1" class="field" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td>
<td class="label">Zip code</td>
<td class="wideField"><input id="postal_code" class="field" disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="label" style="display: none;">Country</td>
<td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input id="country" class="field" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="check" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using a form? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#Examples

Comment: i havenot tried it but i have data on it i just want to know how to pass the field data to other page

Comment: Forms automatically pass their data to another page. The `action` property of a form is like the `href` attribute of a link.

Comment: can you please let me know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from one page to another in many, many ways. The simplest and most fundamental way is the `form` html element.

For the purposes of this I'll assume you have two php pages or Wordpress templates, we'll call them `start-page.php` and `finish-page.php`.

#### start-page.php

```
<!-- If you are using wordpress the action would be
the url of the finish page, not the name of the php file -->
<form action="finish-page.php" method="POST">
  <!-- The name attribute below is important -->
  <input type="text" value="12345" name="postcode">
  <!-- Instead of input type submit, you can also use button type submit -->
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

#### finish-page.php

```
<!--
    the name in quotes in square brackets matches
    the name attribute from the previous page -->
<?php echo $_POST['postcode'] ?>
```

Comment: i have tried it but it not showing any thing on other page