# Wordpress pass data from one page to another

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to pass a text field value in Wordpress from one page to another. User inputs data and I want to display that data on the page he is redirected to.

Following this thread [how to pass a text field value to other page in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831767/how-to-pass-a-text-field-value-to-other-page-in-wordpress) I have

On the input page:

```
<form method='post' action='/page_example/'
  <input type='text' name='serialnumber'>
  <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

And on the Page Example (/page_example/)

```
Your serial number is: <?php echo $_POST['serialnumber'] ?>
```

**Later Edit:**

I have a plugin called PHP everywhere which is supposed to run the PHP codes in pages and posts on Wordpress.

I also tried to insert via shortcodes, but it's not working. It does not pass the text entered on the previous page.

But nothing shows up. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does "on the Page Example" mean - did you just write this code into the post text editor? That should not execute any PHP code contained in the text to begin with. You'll need to either put this somewhere into the page _template_ (where PHP code actually gets executed), or you will have to use one of those plugins, that allow you to execute PHP code in custom places via shortcodes, or something like that.

Comment: I have a plugin called Php Everywhere which is supposed to run PHP codes on posts and pages.

I also tried PHP code in custom places via shortcodes, but it's not working. It breaks the page.

Comment: What happens when you change the form method to `get`, and try and access the value via $_GET?

Comment: You can use php sessions. Not particulerly build for this, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

on the input page

```
<form action="/page-example/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="dataenter" size="20" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

and on the result page (which is a Wordpress page) I used PHP Everywhere Plugin and this code

```
Your serial number is: <?php if(isset($_POST['dataenter'])) {  echo $_POST['dataenter'];} ?>
```

**Edit**: It also works with Code Snippets. I put the PHP code in a snippet and used it as a shortcode to avoid PHP in the editor as per suggestion below.

Comment: This can be a serious security risk.. wordpress not supposed ti run php codes from editor